# How do I set "CustomAttribute6" for a regular AD user?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, powershell

I'm trying to set AD attribute 6 in Powershell to update a user who has no mailbox, and isn't an exchange contact; and is only an AD user  `ObjectClass : user`

The command I'm using is:

```
 get-adobject -filter {mail -eq "danielk@company.com"  } 
         | set-adobject -replace @{CustomAttribute6="daniel.k@company.com" }
```

The error I get is

```
Set-ADObject : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exis
t
Parameter name: CustomAttribute6
At line:1 char:75
+ get-adobject -filter {mail -eq "danielk@asdf.com" } | set-adobject <<
<<  -replace @{CustomAttribute6="daniel.k@nfp.com" }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CN=k\, Dan...e,DC=asdf,DC=
   com:ADObject) [Set-ADObject], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified directory service attribute or val
   ue does not exist
    Parameter name: CustomAttribute6,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm
   ands.SetADObject
```

Since I've simplified this as far as I can go, I don't know what to try next.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct name for the attribute would be `extensionAttribute6`, try that?

Comment: That is perfect.  Do you know how I can "get" that object?  I could have figured this out myself, but get-adobject didn't give me more than 4 attributes

Comment: @makerofthings7 `Get-ADObject <identifier> -Properties *|fl` but it will only show attributes with set values. Beyond that (empty extension attributes for example) you'll have to look at the Schema or browse the object with ADSIEdit